# Is it possible to set a tooltip for a layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, tooltip

When hovering your mouse over a layer, a tooltip appears showing the layer's source. E.g. for a virtual layer:

[image: Layer's tooltip]

Is it possible to change this tooltip either through an existing option or PyQGIS?

---

I noticed the [QgsDataItem class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDataItem.html) has a [setToolTip()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDataItem.html#a332c9b4b3a2dd8102b23d4d864d9a496) method, can something similar be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible removing the layer's source (I will try to investigate), but you may add a *title* and an *abstract* in this way:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()

layer.setTitle('TITLE')
layer.setAbstract('Abstract')
```

You will obtain:

[image]

Comment: Ahh many thanks, I see this can also be edited from `Layer Properties > Metadata`. It's certainly useful as a workaround :)

Comment: @Joseph I initially wanted to post this answer as a comment because I'm sure you want to directly edit the tooltip... I'll edit my answer if I find something more interesting!

Comment: I'm glad you posted it as an answer as this atleast is something I can work with =)

Answer (score 2):

This has been bugging me, I'd like to tweak that myself  - I'd love to be able to hover the mouse over and see the CRS as well as the source.

I managed to hunt down the code that does this. GitHub has a really good full text search, by searching for **abstract setToolTip** I was able to find the code. I'm not a C++ developer, but I can get the gist of C++ code and it seems to tie in with the answer from @mgri

It's in a class called **qgsMapLayerModel**, in a method called **data** [in particular this block](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/8bbb7d92f63aca25f0ced90eae3b5a158516b8d0/src/core/qgsmaplayermodel.cpp#L282)

There seems to be a SIP wrapper for this, so it's probably doable with pyqgis by subclassing this and overriding this method... it's a bit late so I won't attempt to tackle this just now, but hopefully point us both in the right direction :)

Comment: Interesting, great detective work! I'll also take a look at it when I have some spare time but could be doable :)